# Как сделать развертывание сайта через git push?

Tags: git, развертывание

Здравствуйте. С контролем версий сталкиваюсь впервые. Скажите, как сделать, чтобы сразу после push данные обновлялись на хостинге?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас сервер, на котором находится git репозиторий, и хостинг - это одна машина, то с помощью [hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)'а. Если не одна машина, то вам на хостинге нужно будет держать сервер, который будет принимать от hook'а сигнал (http post, например) о том, что репозиторий обновился, и делать pull.
Стоит понять, что удалённый репозиторий и локальный репозиторий - две большие разницы.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее в качестве шутки: хоститься на [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) — их архитектура целиком реализована через git, и иначе обновления и не загрузить, кроме как через `git push heroku master`