# Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git

Tags: git, развертывание, githooks

Есть рабочий сайт, на этом же сервере есть гит-сервер (gitstack).

**Как создать на сервере репозиторий с данным рабочим сайтом?**

Т.е. нужно создать репозиторий, его я клонирую на локальный компьютер, что-то дорабатываю, делаю пуш, и после этого - **то что я только что запушил должно быть сразу видно на рабочем сайте**.

Ясно что лучше иметь отдельно сервер для разработки, отдельно или автоматом деплоить все, но увы - такие условия как я изложил.

Comment: Нужно настраивать хуки, которые по пушу в репозиторий делали деплой. На нормальном git сервере хранится bare-репозиторий, то есть, там нет сорцов в том виде, котором Вы их представляете.

Comment: принял ваш ответ, изучаю git. Понял что нужно использовать linux и остановился сейчас на gitlab'e

Comment: Вообще - это для учебы (для себя) хочу поднять хостинг репозиториев, ну и пушить туда свои сайтики. У меня есть несколько собственных небольших проектов, ftp - надоел, а знание git/gitlab - будет очень полезным

Comment: Еще, кстати, есть третий путь - через системы автоматизации, например Jenkins. Посмотрите хотя бы вкратце на этот вариант, вдруг вам больше подойдет.

Comment: Про пользу от знания git полностью согласен. Еще, кстати, есть GitHub Pages, на котором этот процесс уже реализован. Очень крутая штука. К сайту просто приделан репозиторий, делаете пуш в ветку `master` или `github-pages` - и сайт обновился. https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Развертывание напрямую, без удаленного репозитория и Git-сервера

Требования:

- доступ к серверу по SSH
- на локальной машине установлен git, а также [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) или [git-sync](https://github.com/ianb/git-sync)
- на сервере Git не нужен

#### Что делать?

Не обязательно устанавливать Git на сервере или копировать туда папку `.git`. Чтобы обновить сервер из git-репозитория, вы можете использовать вот такую команду:

```
git ls-files -z | rsync --files-from - --copy-links -av0 . user@server.com:/var/www/project
```

Эта команда копирует все файлы. [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) использует [ssh (secure shell)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), который в любом случае установлен на сервере.

Но при этом вам, вероятно, придется вручную удалить файлы, которые были удалены из проекта (т.е. не изменились, а перестали существовать в очередном коммите).

Вместо rsync можно использовать утилиту [git-sync](https://github.com/ianb/git-sync), написанную [Яном Бикингом](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2012/02/git-as-sync-not-source-control-as-deployment.html). Как утверждает автор, она работает с Git быстрее, чем rsync.

#### Почему это хороший способ?

Чем меньше ПО установлено у вас на сервере, тем более он защищен и тем проще его администрировать и документировать. Кстати, это еще и исключает небоходимость хранить на сервере полный Git-репозиторий со всей историей. Это только усложнило бы задачу по обеспечению безопасности сервера.

(Написано на основе ответа [@Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178597/christian), блога Ian Bicking)

## Развертывание через удаленный репозиторий на сервере.

#### Этот способ сопряжен с риском утечки данных!

> [Были получены исходники 3300 глобальных интернет-проектов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/)

#### Требования:

- доступ к серверу по SSH
- на сервере установлен Git.
- на сервере установлен Git-сервер, например [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) или [Gitstack](http://gitstack.com/).
- на локальной машине установлен Git.

#### Если вы начинаете с сервера с файлами и без репозитория

На сервере в папке с проектом выполните:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m'сообщение, описывающее текущее состояние проекта'
```

И переходите к следующему пункту.

#### Если вы начинаете с сервера с файлами и репозиторием

Выберите на локальной машине папку, где будет располагаться проект. Выполните там:

```
git clone -o production username@webserver:/path/to/htdocs/.git
```

#### Если вы начинаете с локального репозитория

1. Скопируйте свою локальную папку `.git` на сервер.
2. В локальной копии откройте `.git/config` и добавьте ваш сервер как `remote`:

   ```
   [remote "production"]
       url = username@webserver:/path/to/htdocs/.git
   ```

#### Общая часть

1. На сервере замените `.git/hooks/post-update` на код, приведенный ниже в этом ответе.
2. На сервере добавьте этому файлу права на запись:

   ```
   chmod +x .git/hooks/post-update
   ```
3. Теперь, когда вы делаете `git push` с локального репозитория, репозиторий на сервере должен автоматически обновлять рабочую директорию:

   ```
   git push production
   ```

   ## Полезные ссылки по теме:

http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

## post-update hook:

Git-hook нашел на [этом сайте](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitFaq#head-b96f48bc9c925074be9f95c0fce69bcece5f6e73).

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This hook does two things:
#
#  1. update the "info" files that allow the list of references to be
#     queries over dumb transports such as http
#
#  2. if this repository looks like it is a non-bare repository, and
#     the checked-out branch is pushed to, then update the working copy.
#     This makes "push" function somewhat similarly to darcs and bzr.
#
# To enable this hook, make this file executable by "chmod +x post-update". 
git-update-server-info 
is_bare=$(git-config --get --bool core.bare) 
if [ -z "$is_bare" ]
then
      # for compatibility's sake, guess
      git_dir_full=$(cd $GIT_DIR; pwd)
      case $git_dir_full in */.git) is_bare=false;; *) is_bare=true;; esac
fi 
update_wc() {
      ref=$1
      echo "Push to checked out branch $ref" >&2
      if [ ! -f $GIT_DIR/logs/HEAD ]
      then
             echo "E:push to non-bare repository requires a HEAD reflog" >&2
             exit 1
      fi
      if (cd $GIT_WORK_TREE; git-diff-files -q --exit-code >/dev/null)
      then
             wc_dirty=0
      else
             echo "W:unstaged changes found in working copy" >&2
             wc_dirty=1
             desc="working copy"
      fi
      if git diff-index --cached HEAD@{1} >/dev/null
      then
             index_dirty=0
      else
             echo "W:uncommitted, staged changes found" >&2
             index_dirty=1
             if [ -n "$desc" ]
             then
                   desc="$desc and index"
             else
                   desc="index"
             fi
      fi
      if [ "$wc_dirty" -ne 0 -o "$index_dirty" -ne 0 ]
      then
             new=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
             echo "W:stashing dirty $desc - see git-stash(1)" >&2
             ( trap 'echo trapped $$; git symbolic-ref HEAD "'"$ref"'"' 2 3 13 15 ERR EXIT
             git-update-ref --no-deref HEAD HEAD@{1}
             cd $GIT_WORK_TREE
             git stash save "dirty $desc before update to $new";
             git-symbolic-ref HEAD "$ref"
             )
      fi 
      # eye candy - show the WC updates :)
      echo "Updating working copy" >&2
      (cd $GIT_WORK_TREE
      git-diff-index -R --name-status HEAD >&2
      git-reset --hard HEAD)
} 
if [ "$is_bare" = "false" ]
then
      active_branch=`git-symbolic-ref HEAD`
      export GIT_DIR=$(cd $GIT_DIR; pwd)
      GIT_WORK_TREE=${GIT_WORK_TREE-..}
      for ref
      do
             if [ "$ref" = "$active_branch" ]
             then
                   update_wc $ref
             fi
      done
fi
```

Ответ написан на основе [ответов с англоязычного StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push). Дополнил, переработал, собрал в один ответ.

Comment: В своё время был [опрос  на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/211733/) на тему "как вы делаете деплой на продакшн сервера", там кратко описывались все возможные подходы: заливать на ftp файлы, ручное обновление из гит, постхук из гит, деплой через системы CI. Вопрос бы именно о том, как делать деплой через гит, а не в целом о способах разворачивания, но считаю полезным для полноты картины дополнить обзором по способам разворачивания.

Comment: Я мог бы несколько лучшить ответ. Нужно указать, что `git pull` нужно делать под пользователем `apache` или `www-data` (из-под которого работает веб-сервер), что имеет свои тонкости из-за того, что пользователь не имеет шелла. Во-первых, будут проблемы с тем, чтобы просто залогиниться. Во-вторых, возможны проблемы с пробросом ssh-ключей, если не ходить по паролям и не создавать собственный ssh-ключ пользователю `apache`. Ещё  можно автоматизировать операции деплоя через `ansible` - некоторые подводные камни указаны в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548545).

Comment: @AK я на даче, на руках только телефон. Если хотите, можете улучшать или переписывать этот ответ, я не возражаю. Или опубликуйте свой, с меня плюс. )

Comment: @AK а указанный ответ я давно прочитал и плюсанул. )