# Перенос изменений на веб-сервер

Tags: git, развертывание

Есть *git-репозиторий* с  проектом.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы изменения в репозитории переносились на веб-сервер?

Comment: расшифруйте, пожалуйста, что вы подразумеваете под словом «касались».

Comment: Полагаю что имеется ввиду автоматический pull на сервере. Можно просто настроить расписание.

Comment: Точно. Pull на сервер. Как это сделать можете описать или же дать ссылку на документацию.

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдет это решение: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью git post-recieve hook](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/181472)

Comment: А как выполнить git init на веб-сервере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть прибор для этого: [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp). Синхронизировает коммиты  гита с сервором используя FTP.

Comment: А на Windows можно это использовать? а то не разобрался что да как....

Comment: Можно, с mysysgit. [Посмотрите страницу INSTALL.](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/develop/INSTALL.md#windows)

Comment: Получаю ошибку :( http://prntscr.com/7qm2da

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.