# Git не обновляет файлы на сервере

Tags: git

На web сервере автодеплой. Изменил файл в локальной копии проекта, отправил на сервер, все успешно. Но вот на самом сервере после деплоя файл не изменился. Все дело в том, что его кто-то руками правил. Теперь git его не обновляет.
Как к жизни вернуть?

Comment: Может он конфликтует с существующими изменениями.  Попробовать запушить изменения с сервера.

Comment: Вот, я про тоже, есть конфликт. Файл в гите отличается от файла на сервере. По-этому автодеплой не срабатывает. Можно как-то проблемные файлы посмотреть? Хорошо, что я конкретные файлы знаю, что и где меняли. А если бы не знал...

Comment: Я думаю [эта ветка](http://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/2546083) будет полезна для Вас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, сам спросил, сам отвечаю.
Подключаемся к серверу, переходим в папку с проектом и выполняем команду

```
git status
```

Так можно посмотреть модифицированные файлы

Второй командой возвращаем файл в состояние, к котором он находится в репозитории

```
git checkout filename
```

Answer (score 4):

Что точно нужно сделать:

1. Возьмите большую дубинку, можно металлическую.
2. Ударьте по рукам того, кто этими руками правил файлы на сервере напрямую.
3. Навсегда закройте возможность кому бы то ни было менять файлы иначе, как через единственный установленный механизм.

Что, возможно, поможет:

Верно ли я понимаю, что у вас используется post-update hook, который обновляет рабочую область и таким образом осуществляет развертывание? (как тут: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472)) Если так, то нужно

1. Законнектиться к серверу
2. Сделать бэкап того, что руками было изменено.
3. Перейти в папку с Git
4. Сделать `git reset --hard`

В вышеприведенном вопросе есть код hook'a, который в подобных случаях выдает понятные сообщения об ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

для того, чтобы локальные изменения игнорировались, можно вместо:

```
$ git pull
```

использовать, например:

```
$ git fetch && git reset --hard название.ветки
```

Comment: По моему, вы суть вопроса не поняли.

Comment: @Django, вполне возможно. вероятно, слово «автодеплой» не плохо было бы расшифровать.

Comment: @Django как там ваша задача? Про автодеплой расскажете?