# Установка Git на сервере

Tags: git, развертывание

Хочу организовать *Git* на сервере и работу с ним.
Что имеется:

1. Сайт, лежащий под *Git*, локально

Что хочу:

Делая какие то изменения локально, я делаю коммит, и, допустим, в *SmartGit* нажимаю *PUSH*. Файлы отправляются на сервер и указатель автоматом ставится на только что добавленный коммит, т.е., состояние сайта удаленно обновляется.

Другой момент: те же файлы лежат на *BitBucket*, то есть надо и туда файлы потом пушить с локального компа.

Как это организовать? Начиная с установки *git* на удаленном сервере.

Comment: хороший ответ на аналогичный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/178576

Comment: Если я всё правильно понимаю, вы хотите сделать развертывание сайта из локального репозитория Git.  Отметил дублем к соответствующему вопросу и ответу.

Answer (score 0):

На сервер устанавливается git обычным способом, затем в нужной папке инициализируется репозиторий командой `git init`. Затем добавляются удаленные репозитории:

```
git remote set-url origin --push --add <a remote>
git remote set-url origin --push --add <another remote>
```

Если с этих репозиториев нужно еще делать pull, то опцию `--push` нужно пропустить.