# Рабочая версия и версия для разработки в Git

Tags: git

Писал одни проект, дошло время до того, что нужно поднять git-сервер, обеспечить доступ для разработки и параллельно иметь рабочую версию. При необходимости, сливать изменения из версии для разработчиков в рабочую.

Что я сделал:

1. Поставил bonobo git-сервер для IIS7
2. Создал проект, залил все файлы
3. Создал dev-ветку

Теперь я хочу настроить IIS так, чтобы физический путь моего проекта указывал на рабочую ветвь. Начал искать эту самую ветвь в репозитории - так и не нашел. На сколько я понял, Git вообще не хранит файлики в обычном виде, все архивируется и раскидывается по его законам.

Собственно вопрос, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Теперь я хочу настроить IIS так, чтобы физический путь моего проекта указывал на рабочую ветвь.

В общем и целом это выглядит так:

1. bare-репозиторий на сервере (Это должен обеспечивать bonobo)
2. Каждому разработчику какая-то авторизация на сервере (и это тоже)
3. Каждый разработчик работает в своей ветке, которую он ответвляет от develop. Готовые фичи тестируются до слияния, а потом сливаются в develop. Обычно эта процедура строго регламентируется, чтобы нельзя было просто так залить баги или затереть прошлые изменения.

Конкретно:

Новые разработчики клонируют себе репозиторий.

```
git clone git@<git server url>:ProjectName/repo-name.git
```

Забираем нужную ветку

```
git checkout -b origin/develop
```

Создаем свою ветку с фичей

```
git checkout develop
git branch feature-abc
```

Пушим ветку с фичей на удаленный сервер:

```
git push -u origin feature-abc:feature-abc
```

> Git вообще не хранит файлики в обычном виде, все архивируется и раскидывается по его законам

Абсолютно верно.

Внутри каждого репозитория может храниться и рабочая версия, и для разработки, и ещё куча версий - в форме веток (branch). Ветки адресуются внутри собственной файловой системы Git по имени, но не имеют пути во "внешней" файловой системе.

На самом деле Git — это СУБД c контентно-адресуемым хранением и блобами, организованными в ациклические направленные графы. И вам почти никогда не придется лезть руками в его внутреннюю файловую систему, но ради любопытства можете поразбираться.

Вообще, если вы одновременно учитесь использовать Git и администрировать его, то хочу вам порекомендовать сначала использовать готовое решение вроде [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.com). Там есть бесплатные закрытые репозитории для команд до 5 человек включительно. Если только у вас не оборонное предприятие, то предоставляемой безопасности должно быть достаточно. Так вы сможете сконцентрировать усилия на одном направлении, а не распыляться на два.

Если же вы готовы выпустить свой код в opensource, пожалуй, лучшей платформой является [GitHub](http://github.com).

Про развертывание сайта через Git есть достаточно подробный ответ: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472)

Comment: ссылка под словами «ради любопытства можете поразбираться» ведёт, видимо, куда-то не туда.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, я и правда там ссылку затер.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите деплоить в продакшен прямо из git- репозитория то самым лучшим (как в плане контроля так и в плане безопасности) будет написание небольшого скрипта который будет создавать делать clone из вашего репозитория, удалять оттуда папку .git класть потом все в нужное место. Параллельно сможете прикрутить туда всякие бэкапы на случай в следствие деплоя все взорвется.

Почему стоит удалять папку .git (возможно еще что-то, поправьте меня если я не прав) можно почитать тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/. Хотя там речь и идет про svn но в основном проблема одна и та же.

Comment: *Почему стоит удалять* — 1. доступ к каталогу `.git` несложно заблокировать средствами (вероятно) любого *http-сервера*. 2. *docroot* сайта можно держать не в корне рабочей копии репозитория, а глубже. например, в каталоге `www` (или что-нибудь в этом духе). в этом случае у *http-сервера* вообще не будет доступа к каталогу `.git`.

Comment: Резонно, в прочем это уже детали реализации.

Comment: Папка `.git` и файлы рабочей копии необязательно лежат вместе. Можно их развести с помощью `GIT_WORK_TREE`. Можно в хуке сливать файлы в рабочую папку прямо из основной репы (которая bare и лежит где-то совсем отдельно). См. мой ответ.

Comment: В плане безопасности это далеко не лучший метод для развертывания сайта. Можно делать checkout  без файлов .git, а лучше rsync или git-sync.

Answer (score 1):

В [известной статье про развертывание через git](http://gitolite.com/deploy.html) приводятся четыре условия, которые необходимо учитывать:

1. Все файлы из публикуемой ветки должны быть скопированы в каталог развертывания.
2. Файлы, которые были удалены в репе с момента последнего развертывания, должны удалиться из каталога развертывания.
3. Любые изменения в файлах в каталоге развертывания после последнего развертывания следует игнорировать, при соблюдении пп. 1 и 2.
   (Иногда таки полезно обнаружить такие изменения и отменить всё)
4. Неотслеживаемые файлы в каталоге развертывания должны быть оставлены как есть.

Сделать это можно разными способами, например находясь в папке с bare-репозитарием сделать так:

```
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/deploy/dir
git checkout -f master
```

Comment: Хорошая статья. )