# Удаленный доступ на CentOs c Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, centos

Доброго времени суток всем. Ребята подскажите начинающему пожалуйста, каким путем можно зайти удаленно на CentOS с Windows 7. Пробовал поднять VNC сервер на CentOS и потом скачать на шиндовс 7 VNC Viewer чтобы удаленно подключиться к CentOS. Подключиться кончен же не получилось, может у кого есть опыт в этом? Подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Эмм, по SSH? ...

Comment: В Windows используйте ssh-клиента, [`putty`](http://www.putty.org/), например.

Comment: По putty получается подключиться, но я бы хотел к рабочему столу CentOs. По ssh есть подключение, но только к консоли.

Comment: *По ssh есть подключение* — для управления сервером этого **более** чем достаточно.

Comment: Уважаемый alexander barakin, я понимаю, что этого более чем достаточно, но проблема в том что на удаленном сервере мне нужно запускать среду разработки и периодически тестировать код. Изначально, я говорил о доступе к рабочему столу, т.е. к оболочке. Как мне это сделать если есть доступ по ssh тогда ?

Comment: @Rusikhabhabr ...на удаленном **сервере** мне нужно запускать **среду разработки**... - как же с такими костылями можно разрабатывать что-то? Вам скорей нужно пересмотреть подход к разработке/тестированию и деплою. А также пересмотреть понимание философии сервера и клиента.

Comment: @Rusikhabhabr Если надо запускать среду разработки и тестировать код - VNC - плохой вариант. Смотрите в сторону X2GO.

Comment: [CentOS - Установка и конфигурирование SSH](http://sys-admin.kz/os/nix/182-centos-install-and-configure-openssh.html), [SSH Client Windows](http://www.putty.org/)

Comment: Добро пожаловать в юниксовый мир. :) Чтобы освоиться с командной строкой, могу порекомендовать вам курс на codecademy: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-the-command-line

Comment: Соглашусь с предыдущим комментатором: если вам требуется на удаленном сервере запускать среду разработки - у вас проблемы в построении процесса разработки и со временем будет только сложнее. Рекомендую изучить способы разрабатывать локально, а потом приложение развертывать на сервере. Если будут вопросы по реализации - задавайте их тут с меткой [tag:развертывание]. Если это у вас сайт - то вот готовое решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472

Comment: @approximatenumber у меня есть опыт работы с шиндовс, с linux у меня его нет, но хотелось бы получить. И как любой начинающий я могу ошибаться в своих подходах, поэтому прошу строго меня не судить. Именно поэтому я попросил помощи у знающих указав, что я начинающий. Я бы пересмотрел, но в какую сторону смотреть пока не знаю. По позже создам топик, где подниму очередной нубский вопрос о том, как все таки нужно делать, при разработке мобильных приложений с клиент-северной моделью. Если конечно таких постов не будет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо за ваши ответы, приму к сведению!

Comment: @Rusikhabhabr задавайте обязательно. А пока просто знайте, что такое явления, как процесс разработки кода на сервере - плохо. Тем более, сервер с графическим окружением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вариант с VNC:

   Установить сервер:

   ```
   yum install vnc-server
   ```

   Запустить без паролей с полным доступом:

   ```
   x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess
   ```
2. Вариант с TeamViewer:

   Качаем:

   ```
   wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer.i686.rpm
   ```

   Ставим:

   ```
   sudo rpm -ihv teamviewer.i686.rpm
   ```

Но это всё, если CentOS **десктопный**. Если это всё-таки сервер - лучше `ssh` пока ничего нет (системы управления конфигурацией не в счёт). И тут есть [Putty](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), [Kitty](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/), [ttssh2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tera_Term) и даже через [браузер](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne) можно найти.

Comment: т.е. вариант доступа к рабочему столу сервера лучше не использовать по соображениям безопасности? Я правильно вас понял? Доступ ssh будет куда надежнее, чем через vnc?

Comment: vnc тоже можно пустить или через ssh или через vpn. Вопрос в другом - зачем на сервере рабочий стол? От того, что на сервер накатили гуи - у него не появится гуёвых конфигураторов какого-нибудь апача или vsftpd. Графика на сервере НЕ НУЖНА.

Comment: Поднял teamviewer и ssh.

Comment: А тимвьювер зачем?

Comment: Для удобства, я с linux системами пока что на Вы поэтому периодически надо будет заходить на сервер как на десктопный. Сервер экспериментальный, хочу попробовать сделать мобильное приложение с серверной частью на Linux и клиентом на android. Вот так.

Comment: @Rusik habhabr забудьте сразу про десктоп на сервере и про гуи. Сразу привыкайте к консоли и к ssh. Поймите, что это просто иной подход в принципе. На windows свет клином не сошелся. Вы же не подключаете к смартфону мышку? Привыкли тыкать пальцем в него? Так и здесь... сразу просто работайте так как принято на этой системе, а не пробуйте разные костыли.

Comment: @MaxZS Спасибо за ценный совет, буду стараться использоваться только консоль.

Comment: @Rusikhabhabr зайдя на сервер как на десктоп, вы не увидите ничего полезного. Всё самое ценное - в командной строке ))

Comment: @Rusikhabhabr Учтите, что установив teamviewer - к вашему серверу получает доступ также и соответствующая корпорация. Также, рекомендую обратить внимание на то, сколько памяти занимает их демон. Всё-таки на Linux лучше использовать открытые решения, а не проприетарные.

Comment: Добавлю ещё. Когда прога заработает и её начнут ставить - никто ради неё не будет ставить gui на свой сервер. А это - сразу 99% пользователей.

Да, как говорил выше @MaxZS - надо поменять своё мышление, чтобы работать с *nix. Я бы начал именно с этого, а не с тимвьювера\внц. Будет сложно, но оно того стоит.

Comment: teamview не рекомендовал бы. Все попытки его установить уводили на перезагрузку или жуткие тормоза

Answer (score 4):

SSH - это универсальный и оптимальный вариант, всегда доступен на любом Linux-дистрибутиве. Даёт полный доступ из командной строки. Клиент для Windows: http://www.putty.org/

Протокол VNC - даёт возможность графического удалённого доступа, но, фактически, посылает скриншоты. Также есть некоторые нюансы с автозагрузкой (`vino` требуется что бы кто-то вошёл в систему, перед тем как он начёнт работать, если речь идёт о сервере - то лучше использовать `x11vnc` для этого, его можно использовать сразу с загрузкой X11)

Но если требуется графический удалённый доступ, но более эффективный (в плане трафика, прежде всего), чем VNC, то лучше использовать технологии NX или X2GO (по функционалу больше похожи на RDP, то есть пригодны и для терминального сервера). Инструкции по установке и настройке этих протоколов для CentOS легко ищутся в сети, не забудьте только указать номер версии вашей CentOS.

Для вашей задачи (тестирование и разработка), на мой взгляд, предпочтительнее использовать X2GO, устанавливается так:

```
yum install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
```

Клиент для Windows: http://code.x2go.org/releases/binary-win32/x2goclient/releases/

У этого протокола множество возможностей, в том числе общий буфер обмена, работа в режиме одного окна и т.п. ИНструкция на русском для  CentOS: http://palexa.pp.ua/terminal-server/x2go/192-terminalnyj-server-na-linux-centos-6-x2go-terminal-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Возможно заинтересует данный проект: [xpra](https://xpra.org/). Позволяет запускать ПО на удаленном хосте с выводом окна приложения на локальном мониторе. Поддерживает перенаправление буфера обмена, звука, принтеров и локальных дисков. Работает поверх ssh. Доступен для: Microsoft Windows, Apple Mac OS X и Linux. В дополнение к xpra: [winswitch](http://winswitch.org/about/) - фронт-энд для управления подключениями xpra (а так же VNC, NX, RDP, и т.д.)