# Деплой проекта из Gitlab

Tags: git, развертывание, gitlab

Допустим есть проект в gitlab'e - `test.git`. В процессе разработки, приходят мержреквесты, и после мержа в мастер я хочу выкатить релиз на production. Для этого, я иду на сервер и выполняю там такую команду:

`git archive --remote=/git-data/repositories/root/test.git master | tar -x -C /sites/test/`

Но, можно ли, это сделать из gitlab'a, чтобы не ходить на сервер? И например, в моем случае, это проект на node.js, и после того как будет выполнена команда `git archive`, хотелось бы выполнить еще перезапуск сервера `node /sites/test/restart.js --use_strict`.

*p.s. читал про `builds` но так и не понял как это работает, объясните пожалуйста подробнее как это устроено, и как решить мою задачу.*

Comment: Вот такое решение вам подойдет? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/181472 В целом хранить репозиторий на вашем боевом сервере - опасно. Слишком легко протерять исходный код. А сделать пакет и подтянуть его через npm вы можете? Если да, идите этим путём. Работа через пакеты даст вам возможность четко версионироваться, легко релизить и откатывать релизы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вообще в планах держать gitlab на отдельном сервере, но я пока учусь, хочу во всем разобраться. Спасибо за пример по ссылке, но там немного не то что я хочу. Там описано как сделать хук post update, но он же будет срабатывать после каждого пуша. А я хочу сделать так чтобы по нажатии какой-нибудь кнопки `build` в гитлабе происходил деплой нужной ветки. Насчет npm, есть любая возможность, я же пытаюсь обучится, но я незнаком с этим способом.

Comment: А, теперь понял, что за `builds` - из гитлаба. Это инструмент для того чтобы собрать, задеплоить и протестировать ваш код **до** того, как он попадёт в master. Это один из возможных способов запускать развертывание - но не единственный. При этом сам сценарий развертывания тоже может быть реализован множеством способов.

Comment: В целом, когда для развертывания нужна последовательность действий, хорошо подходят системы управления конфигурацией push-типа, например [tag:ansible], [tag:chef]. Если вас устроит решение на ansible, могу написать ответ. Вот неплохая статья о развертывании node.js через ansible. http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/06/02/node-js-in-production/

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, напишите, премного вам благодарен! И если знаете   про то как использовать `builds` это будет здорово, может быть это все можно связать...

Comment: постараюсь написать, но сегодня не успею уже точно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, было бы очень здорово, я пока еще не разобрался во всем

Comment: Не прошло и года, вот вам отличное руководство по деплою именно из гитлаба: [GitLab CI: Учимся деплоить](https://habrahabr.ru/company/softmart/blog/310502/)