# работа с Git и GitHub объединение веток

Tags: git, github

В общем есть сайт на отдельном хостинге на котором идут доработки и рабочий сайт на другом хосте, в обоих случаях на хостинге установлен git.

Кода подрубаешься по ssh  к тестовому сайту то командой `git branch` я вижу что нахожусь в нужной мне ветке в которой идут доработки, после того как я закончил с правками делаю коммиты, далее `git push origin my_test_branch`.

После захожу в аккаунт на GitHub и как я понял нужно сравнить ветки, за это отвечает кнопка `Pull requests` показываются так понимаю все файлы которые затронуты и конфликты с веткой `master`
далее так понимаю я объединяю ветки кнопкой `merge` пишется что то вроде слияние успешно конфликтов нет, но тут вопрос, как теперь увидеть изменения на рабочем сайте?

Нужно зайти по SSH и выполнить какие то команды git ? если набрать git branch я не вижу там своей ветки это потому что не я создавал на хостинге репозиторий?

Помогите разобраться, проект реальный и нужно сделать очень срочно поэтому написал сюда, с git работаю всего несколько часов, извиняюсь если что то выразил не правильно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Comment: там мне кажется другая проблема, я хочу понять как мне подключившись к рабочему сайту, с ветки master с которой я объединил свою , т.е проапдейтить сайт, чтоб изменения вступили в силу

Comment: Вообще не храните репозиторий Git на своем хостинге. Он занимает лишнее место, а ещё в результате вашей неосторожности злоумышленники могут получить доступ ко всему вашему коду. Лучше посмотрите в сторону `rsync` или `git-sync`.

Answer (score 1):

самый простой воркфлоу  для одиночки:

- идете на **хостинг** по ssh,
- в настройках вебсервера запрещаете доступ к  папке .git, либо инициализируете репозиторий на уровень выше (чтобы директория была недоступна клиентам через браузер)
- `git init && git add .  && git commit -m "init"`
- на **локальном компьютере** - `git clone ssh://хостинг/путь/к/каталогу/c/.git/`
  делаете изменения, потом `git add . && git commit -m "changes" && git push`
- остальные репозитории добавляете как `git remote add upstream  путь_к_гитхабу_или_другому_компу`

основной сайт у вас будет по дефолту ремоутом с именем origin,  для других ремоутов имена сами выбираете.

допустим, кто-то изменил код на **гитхабе**: вы делаете на **локальном компьютере:**

`git fetch upstream` # вытянули изменения с **гитхаба**

`git merge upstream/имя_ветки_с_изменениями` # смерджили в текущую ветку изменения  c апстрима (**гитхаб**)

если мердж прошел с конфликтами - правите ручками. либо ставьте git difftool (meld, и т.д.) / или intellijidea, где мердж идеальный

`git push origin`  # пушите изменения на **хостинг**,

при желании, конечно, вы можете добавить прямо на *хостинге* апстрим github и пулить изменения прямо с него. на практике это неудобно и к тому же, вместо двух актуальных копий кода сайта (у вас и на хостинге) вы только одну имеете (на хостинге)

остальное гуглите

Comment: изменения делаются на разных хостингах, т.е серверах, ветки слил в аккаунте на гитхаб, до меня человек уже работал и вносил изменения но так получилось что толком мне нечего не объяснили, и тут вопрос, получается если ветка master обновлена, то мне остается как то обновить репозиторий на хостинге рабочего сайта, как это сделать я не совсем понимаю

Comment: обновил ответ, смотрите

Comment: я извиняюсь но походу я туплю что то, вы дали развернутый и хороший ответ, но я мало что то запутался, разве нельзя просто  командой на хостинге просто загрузить обновления ветки ?

Comment: (про это в последнем абзаце написано) вам надо сначала создать иницализировать репозиторий на хостинге. добавить к нему remote - откуда гит будет скачивать обновления. если вы сделаете это прямо на хостинге, минуя локальный комп - оно может сработать. если возникнут конфликты, сайт скорее всего ляжет, а вам придется делать `git merge --abort`

Comment: гораздо проще склонировать версию с хостинга, вмерджить в нее изменения со второго сервера и запушить снова на хостинг.

Comment: я делаю сейчас так, с помощью проги SmartGit скачиваю как вы и сказали удаленный репозиторий, получается мне в него вносить изменения не нужно т.к я уже объединил ветки на гитхабе, и теперь я сделал пуш, при этом при клонирование запрашивался private key, у себя в профиле я его не нашел и он не генерировался, уточню что мой профиль добавлен в приватный рипозиторий из за этого могут быть проблемы?

Comment: Скорее всего я снова не верно делаю, сделал пуш себе же в локальный репозиторий,  дополнил, хотя нет вроде как они при пуше уходят на удаленный репозиторий

Comment: извините, я уж не знаю, чем вам помочь. разве что пойти поспать и завтра почитать по гитхабу и гиту маленькие статьи для начинающих. поэкспериментировать.

Comment: да, спасибо вам большое что терпеливо отвечали мне, буду пытаться решить задачу.