# Редактор кода под linux с удалённым подключением к другому серверу linux

Tags: linux, редактор, доступ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, простенький редактор для php/js под linux чтобы была возможность удалённого подключения к другому серверу и быстрому редактирования кода.

Под windows использую notepad++ с расширением и это идеальное решения для меня, а вот на linux как не пытался найти что-то похожее, ничего не вышло. Пробовал настроить phpstorm или другие ide, но они все копируют проект и редактирует уже локально, что мне неудобно. Вообще никаких монстров с рефактором не надо, достаточно просто редактора с подсветкой синтаксиса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Настраивать подключение в самом редакторе - довольно странная практика. Возможно, какой-то редактор так умеет, но я с таким не встречался. Есть способы гораздо проще.

1. Редактировать весь код локально, сохранять в систему контроля версий, быстро развертывать на сервере. Это предпочтительный вариант. Необязательно производить доставку кода на сервер с помощью git, вполне достаточно освоить rsync. Пример реализации как через git, так и rsync: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472).

   Плюсы:

   - меньше шансов всё испортить прямо на бою
   - легко масштабируется
   - воспроизводимые результаты
   - нарабатываете полезные навыки для работы с крупными командными проектами
2. Сначала зайти по SSH и потом редактировать. Подсветка кода есть в vim, emacs (но нужны плагины).

   ```
   ssh user@somehost
   vim ~/helloworld.txt
   ```
3. Примонтировать удалённую файловую систему и работать локально в любом редакторе. Хоть в полновесной IDE. KoVadim подсказывает отличную инструкцию от DigitalOcean: [How To Use SSHFS to Mount Remote File Systems Over SSH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

   ```
   # базовые инструкции есть тут
   man mount
   ```

Comment: 1. Неудобно. Проекты маленькие, бекапы делаю самостоятельно время от времени, пока ничего не потерял. Мне нужно чтобы я отредактировал файл, нажал ctrl + s и всё сразу обновилось на сайте, без пуша в терминале и прочего. По ссылке что вы дали кучу действий надо проделать, в том числе настраивать сервер... Я понимаю, когда работаешь в команде и над большими проектами, тогда это нужно, но когда всем подряд советуют использовать это - в общем этот подход не для меня.
2, 3 спасибо за варианты, попробую.

Comment: @Floyat учитесь этому сейчас, пока работаете над маленькими проектами, риски ваши невысоки, а ошибки обходятся дёшево. Разумеется, это если вы хотите в будущем работать в команде и/или над большими проектами.

Comment: на [do](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) есть чудная инструкция, как все это настроить. В результате удаленная папка будет прямо в локальной файловой системе. И будет работать как обычная файловая система (открываться в любой программе), просто чуточку тормознее (но это уже от подключения зависит).

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, добавлю в ответ.

Comment: Дело не в непонимании работы систем контроля версий. С этим разберется любой при желании. Дело именно в удобстве. Я не хочу использовать терминал после каждой правки, это неудобно. Я не хочу настраивать сервер, устанавливать туда что-то, всё и без того настроено и отлично работает. Я хочу открыть редактор, вбить туда путь до сервера и через 3 минуты уже работать над новым проектом, который вот только что создал. Конечно, люди, работающие в крупных проектах, меня не поймут совсем, но вот те, кто занимаются простым фрилансом или разработками в маленьких офисах, запросто.

Comment: Если Вы хотите работать в линуксе (и с линукс серверами - а для современного веб-разработчика это почти неизбежно), Вам нужно освоить и полюбить терминал.

Comment: @KoVadim это мне или Floyat?

Comment: я думаю, это понятно, что это для @Floyat.

Comment: @Floyat вы можете копировать файлы на сервер через rsync / git-sync, это очень быстро.

Answer (score 4):

К вашим услугам:

- mcedit
- nano
- vi
- emacs

Работают через консоль ssh.

Но правильный workflow подразумевает, что вы работаете у себя в репозитарии, а потом делаете `push` на сервер, где есть bare-репозитарий с хуком, который развертывает все это дело на прод.

Answer (score 0):

Если под виндой работал с `Notepad++`, то можно посмотреть в сторону [Notepadqq](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/wp/).

Comment: Устанавливал. Но, к сожалению, не нашёл в нём добавление расширений и никаких возможностей к подключению к ssh аналогично notepad++. Может надо делать через терминал, это не пробовал.

Comment: Для ssh под линуксом есть sshfs. Каждая прога - для своей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: Sublime text 3 + [sftp](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)

Очень давно уже использую эту связку

Comment: SFTP очень медленный протокол. Тем более для таких задач. ИМХО, разумеется.

Answer (score 0):

Comodo точно так умеет. Это если не оффтопить и чётко отвечать исключительно на заданный вопрос. Правда, ни фига он не простенький... Но и до "монстров" типа PHPStorm ему далеко :) в общем, удачи