# развёртывание проекта с помощью git push

Tags: git, git-push

имеется:

- сервер с *git-ом* и доступом по протоколу *ssh*
- на сервере в каталоге `/путь/к/` создано обыкновенное (не-bare) *git-хранилище* командой `git init`
- у пользователя, от имени которого подключаюсь, есть права на запись в этот каталог

требуется:

- чтобы при отправке изменений командой *git push* **в любую ветку** из локального клона этого хранилища обновлённые файлы тут же появлялись на сервере в рабочем каталоге `/путь/к/` именно в том виде, как они представленны в этой самой ветке

да, я знаю про [подводные камни](http://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/). меры приняты.

как настроить хранилище на сервере, чтобы оно работало именно так, как мне требуется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### на сервере:

1. в каталоге `/путь/к/` выполните команду:

   ```
   $ git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
   ```
2. в хранилище (`/путь/к/.git/`) создайте файл `/путь/к/.git/hooks/post-update` следующего содержания:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   GIT_WORK_TREE=$(dirname $PWD) git reset --hard $(git rev-parse $1)
   ```
3. добавьте этому файлу биты исполнимости:

   ```
   $ chmod +x /путь/к/.git/hooks/post-update
   ```

### всё.

теперь можете клонировать это хранилище себе локально:

```
$ git clone пользователь@сервер:/путь/к/
```

добавлять файлы, ветки, коммитить и отправлять изменения на сервер командой *git push* (понятно, что если ветки на сервере ещё не существует, надо будет её указать, например, так: `git push origin ветка`).

---

если вдруг понадобится переключиться на другой коммит/ветку без создания нового коммита, то придётся «вручную» на сервере выполнить (в каталоге `/путь/к/`) `git checkout -f ...` или `git reset --hard ...`

---

навеяно этими вопросами (и ответами к ним) с одной целью — упростить процесс:

- [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576)
- [Deploy a project using Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279169/4827341)