# Ansible: форвард ssh-агента и sudo

Tags: centos, ssh, ansible

Имеется командный сервер с ansible с именем server-ansible и настраиваемый сервер test-web-server-01

В плейбуке/роли необходимо залогиниться пользователем apache и склонировать удалённый репозиторий с сервера test-git-01. SELinux на обоих машинах (кстати, Centos7) включен.

В глобальный файл `known_hosts` (`/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`) при помощи [known_hosts_module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/known_hosts_module.html) заранее установлен ключ гит-сервера:

```
- name: git storage pubkey
  known_hosts:
    path='/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts'
    name='test-git-01'
    key="{{ lookup('file', 'files/ssh_keys/pubkeys/test-git-01.pub') }}"
```

(Файл ключа получается вручную командой `ssh-keyscan test-git-01>test-git-01.pub`)

Тем не менее, при попытке выполнения команд `git clone` (`git pull` и т.п.) получаем ошибку.

```
- name: clone repository
  git:
   repo: git@test-git-01:testgroup/testrepo.git
   dest: "/www/testsite.ru/htdocs/"
  become: true
  become_user: apache
```

Это логично: у пользователя apache нет ssh-ключа и подключиться к серверу невозможно.

Как вариант решения не рассматривается возможность создания пользователю apache собственного ключа через `sudo -u apache ssh-keygen -t rsa` и прописывание его на гит-сервере.

Хочется сделать следующее: чтобы при подключении пользователя ansible его ssh-ключ пробрасывался пользователю apache. Так как с этим ключом можно работать с git-сервером, то безопаснее, если возможность работы у пользвателя apache будет не постоянно, а лишь на время работы скриптов ansible.

Как корректно настроить форвард ssh-ключей в ansible?

P.S. Update. Ниже описано мой собственный вариант, к которому я когда-то пришёл и который потом выискивал на английском so. Можно было этот вариант сразу опубликовать в режиме вопрос-ответ, но мне интересно почитать про другие возможные варианты решения задачи (м.б. расстановка ACL?), возможно будет предложена ещё более лучшая практика. Поэтому галку я пока ставить не собираюсь.

Comment: А кстати да: квартал прошёл. Поправил строку экспорта ключей для более общего случая - остальное вроде нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На английском stackoverflow есть два вопроса, которые практически полностью раскрывают ответ.

В [первом из них](https://serverfault.com/questions/107187/ssh-agent-forwarding-and-sudo-to-another-user) описана настройка форвардинга для командной строки (обратите внимание: настройка пользователя root отличается от настройки других пользователей)

[Во втором](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091956/ansible-and-forwardagent-for-sudo-user) описывается как раз настройка ansible и приводится пара полезных ссылок: на [issue на гитхабе](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7235#issuecomment-45842303) и уже приведённая ссылка.

Итоговое решение получается следующим:

Добавить в `ansible.cfg` строки:

```
[defaults]
sudo_flags=-HE
```

Дать apache доступ к проброшенному ключу:

```
- name: grant access to apache
      file: group=apache mode=g+rwx path={{item}}
      with_items:
      - "{{ ansible_env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK|dirname }}"
      - "{{ ansible_env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK }}"
```

В принципе, это всё. Незначительная тонкость связана с тем, почему я могу опустить `become: false` -- потому что изначально у меня на всех машинах заблокирован доступ root по SSH и поэтому я не могу им подключаться.