# Как использовать ключи из /etc/ssh_known_hosts в скриптах git

Tags: git, ssh, ansible

Сценарий. Пользователь alice заходит на сервер msk-web-01 (centos7.2, selinux включен) по своему ssh ключу и хочет в папке /www/mysite.ru/htdocs/ (владелец папки -- пользователь apache) запустить команду git pull.

Для этого написан небольшой батник:

```
#!/bin/sh

#see http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548545/ for details
sudo setfacl -m apache:x   $(dirname "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK")
sudo setfacl -m apache:rwx "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"

cd /www/mysite.ru/htdocs/
pwd
sudo su -s /bin/sh apache -c "/usr/bin/git pull"
....
```

И он работает... выдавая многочисленные предупреждения:

> ```
> /www/site1.ru/htdocs
> Could not create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.ssh'.
> Failed to add the ECDSA host key for IP address '1.2.3.4' to the list of known hosts (/usr/share/httpd/.ssh/known_ho).
> Already up-to-date.
> /www/site2.ru/htdocs
> Could not create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.ssh'.
> Failed to add the ECDSA host key for IP address '1.2.3.4' to the list of known hosts (/usr/share/httpd/.ssh/known_ho).
> Already up-to-date.
> ```

Задача -- избавиться от этих лишних записей, добившись чистого вывода при помощи добавления записей в глобальный known_hosts.

Требуемый эффект можно получить если создать `/usr/share/httpd/.ssh/known_hosts` со строкой `CheckHostIP no`:

> ```
> /www/site1.ru/htdocs
> Already up-to-date.
> /www/site2.ru/htdocs
> Already up-to-date.
> /www/site3.ru/htdocs
> Already up-to-date.
> ```

Разумеется, такой способ не рассматривается как решение задачи, так же как и другие обходные пути типа "совсем отключить проверку" (скажем, [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772190/passing-ssh-options-to-git-clone) или [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299651/git-says-warning-permanently-added-to-the-list-of-known-hosts))

PS Ключи сохранял одним из двух способов, первый:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa git.mycomany.ru >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

второй:

```
ssh-keyscan git.mycomany.ru >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

Разница не особо велика: в первом случае Failed to add the RSA host, во втором - Failed to add the ECDSA host key.

И даже так с горя:

```
ssh-keyscan git.mycomany.ru,1.2.3.4 >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

Comment: `/usr/share/httpd` — это домашний каталог какого пользователя? (`$ grep /usr/share/httpd /etc/passwd`)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это каталог пользователя apache в centos. Каталога .ssh там нет, т.к. пользователь без шелла.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/107187/292034 — это чтобы не требовалось манипуляций с acl-ами.

Comment: Вы ссылаетесь на топик, который я многократно перечитывал и отрабатывал разные аспекты. Там всё верно написано, а вот манипуляции с acl неизбежно понадобятся: pageant пробрасывает ключ каждый раз в случайную папку, поэтому один раз и навсегда права не установить (вы же не хотите давать постоянный доступ на всю папку /tmp пользователям).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, всё оказалось достаточно просто.

Сначала ещё раз о постановке задачи. Есть ряд доверенных серверов организации, между которыми сотрудникам нужно перемещаться с сохранением авторизации (ForwardAgent), поэтому нужно уметь заполнять файл `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` доверенными данными.

Во-первых, гит в своём общении с удалёнными репозиториями по протоколу ssh полагается на системные утилиты, особых настроек ssh-подключения нет -- можно [почитать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772190/passing-ssh-options-to-git-clone) про хаки с созданием файла ssh и экспортированием переменной GIT_SSH. Поэтому изначально в вопросе было больше про ssh, чем про конкретно git.

Во-вторых, когда я начал разбираться с ключами (rsa, dsa, esdca) и версиями протоколов -- я решил не только абстрагироваться от гит, но и от ансибл - чтобы не влияло, на всякий случай.

После тестов у меня получилось, что ключи были сгенерированы правильно, настройки ssh (как дефолтные центоса, так и мои кастомные) тоже не влияют на работу.

Всё, что нужно -- это сдампить отпечатки и записать в общий known_hosts:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa git.mycomany.ru >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

Включение хеширования не влияет на итог - тоже. А что влияет?

Как ни странно -- выяснилось, что влияет ansible. Если файла /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts на диске нет -- он создаёт файл с правами rw-r--r-- но стоит лишь ещё раз запустить повторно -- права чудесным образом становятся rw-------
Разумеется, что процессы, которые хотят прочитать хранилище и проверить, нет ли там такого отпечатка обламываются и ничего не находят. Стоит лишь восстановить права на файл -- и работа снова восстанавливается.

Пример заполнения ключей практически такой же, как и в [документации](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/known_hosts_module.html):

```
- name: global pubkes for servers
  known_hosts:
    path='/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts'
    name='{{ item }}'
    key="{{ lookup('file', 'files/pubkeys/{{ item }}.pub') }}"
  with_items:
    - git.mycompany.ru
```

Я хотел было создать баг на гитхабе -- но перед заведением поискал, нет ли готового. И нашёл, вот: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/2513

Answer (score 4):

1. как выяснилось в комментариях, `/usr/share/httpd` — это домашний каталог пользователя `apache`. именно этому пользователю и должен принадлежать каталог (и всё его содержимое) `/usr/share/httpd/.ssh`:

   ```
   $ sudo chown -R apache /usr/share/httpd/.ssh
   ```

   также он должен быть доступен только самому пользователю:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod -R go= /usr/share/httpd/.ssh
   ```
2. добавить публичные ключи (по умолчанию — типов *rsa*, *ecdsa* и *ed25519* — см. `$ man ssh-keyscan`) машины `git.mycompany.ru` в файл «известных хостов» пользователя `apache` (`/usr/share/httpd/.ssh/known_hosts`) можно так:

   ```
   $ ssh-keyscan git.mycompany.ru | sudo tee -a /usr/share/httpd/.ssh/known_hosts
   ```

   если этот файл до этого не существовал, команды из первого пункта надо повторить после этой операции.
3. вместо манипуляций с *acl*-ами (`setfacl ...`) лучше добавить строку

   ```
   Defaults    env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
   ```

   в `/etc/sudoers` (или даже ещё лучше — в файл с произвольным именем, не содержащем точек и тильд в имени, в каталоге `/etc/sudoers.d`). подробнее см., например, [здесь](https://serverfault.com/a/118932/292034). редактировать эти файлы лучше через «обёртку» `visudo` — см., например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552377/178576).

#### уточнение в связи с требованием не использовать каталог `~/.ssh` пользователя `apache`.

1. чтобы не использовать `~/.ssh/config`, но иметь возможность указать особую конфигурацию для конкретного пользователя, можно воспользоваться директивой `match user` в `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, добавив **в конец** (это важно — см. `$ man ssh_config` на предмет опции `match`) этого файла примерно следующее:

   ```
   match user apache
   # какие-либо персональные настройки для пользователя apache
   ```
2. чтобы процесс *ssh* не использовал `~/.ssh/knonw_hosts`, можно (способом, описанным в предыдущем пункте) переопределить для данного пользователя значение конфигурационной переменной `userknownhostsfile`, указав в ней, например, файл `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` (или любой другой доступный пользователю для чтения):

   ```
   userknownhostsfile /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
   ```

   нужные ключи в этот файл, разумеется, уже должны быть добавлены заранее. например, тем способом, что описан во втором пункте первой части ответа.
3. возможно, для пользователей по умолчанию включена необходимость хешировать записи в `known_hosts`, тогда процесс *ssh* попытается перезаписать файл с ключами. чтобы он этого не делал, укажите (хотя бы для этого пользователя) не хешировать записи, добавив (как описано в первом пункте) строку:

   ```
   hashknownhosts no
   ```

Comment: Александр, спасибо за готовность помочь, но ваш ответ решительно идёт совершенно не в ту сторону: мейнтейнеры последовательно убирают права служебным учёткам, от которых запускаются демоны - а вы предлагаете их снова вернуть (отдать обратно каталог .ssh). В общем-то когда-то у меня так и было, вебсервисы стартовали из-под полноценных учёток с шеллом. Но мою печень квартально клюют безопасники и пройдя с десяток аудитов могу уже примерно откинуть решения с бОльшим числом векторов атаки. А такое решение я уже опробовал и в вопросе написал, что оно заведомо не подходит.

Comment: Идеальное решение: использовать общесистемный файл ssh_known_hosts, в который я пропишу корректный ключ. При этом не нужно будет вообще создавать каталог .ssh в /usr/share/httpd/ - все ключи на сервера доставляются ansible при изменениях инфраструктуры.

Comment: @AK, не понятно, как эти ваши «безопасники» не замечают наличия git-хранилища в корне сайтов и вообще запуск каких-либо процессов от имени без-шеллового пользователя. // отключать проверку host-ключей вовсе не обязательно. чтобы ssh не пытался добавить ключ, он уже должен быть в файле known_hosts, соответственно, надо просто указать ssh использовать как *userknownhostsfile* глобальный файл `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`, ну или любой другой читабельный, в который уже добавлены нужные ключи.

Comment: @AK, такую пер-юзерную настройку можно сделать без использования `~/.ssh/config`, прямо в `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` с помощью директивы `match user`.

Comment: @AK, обновил ответ, перенеся существенное из комментариев.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что если указать UserKnownHostsFile=/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts то он будет пытаться дописать туда ключи, как будто их там нет. Причём писать не в формате ssh_known_hosts, а в формате ~/.ssh/known_hosts - поэтому видимо и "рекомендации" писать UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null Про match_user не понял совета, позже попробую вчитаться внимательнее.

Comment: @AK, 1. что это за два «формата»? и в том и в другом файле ключи записываются в **одном** формате. возможно, ssh пытается захэшировать строку. так укажите (хотя бы этому пользователю) `hashknownhosts no`. 2. не `match_user`, а `match user`. см. `man ssh_config` на предмет директивы `match`. а пример я привёл.