# Как настроить git с подключением репозиториям gitlab на сайте?

Tags: git

Мне необходимо настроить git с подключением репозитория к gitlab. При написании команд возникает ошибка `-bash: git: command not found`. В чём может быть проблема и как это можно исправить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот с инструкциями из GitLab:

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют.

Comment: вам сначала нужно установить Git, но вы не предоставили никакой информации об используемой платформе, поэтому на этот вопрос нельзя однозначно ответить.

Comment: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Answer (score 6):

Баш явно намекает, что git не установлен. Вариантов решения два - правильный и неправильный. Либо установить git на сервере (`apt-get install git` скорее всего, если там убунту, для других вариантов есть свои команды). Либо правильный - на сервер нужно ставить систему деплоя, а не пулить репозиторий.

Comment: Теперь выдает ошибку:
-bash: apt: command not found

Comment: @linki_plus `apt-get install git`

Comment: @linki_plus если и `apt-get install` не сработает, напишите в вопросе, какая у вас ОС. А лучше пойдите правильным путём и настройте систему деплоя.