# git hook, что-бы сделать git pull на удалённом клоне

Tags: git, bash, ssh, githooks

Добрый день,

У меня два клона на:

- локальной машине - `local`
- удаленной машине A - `RM-A`

и git репозиторий на удаленной машине B - `RM-B`

Как прописать hook на `RM-B`, что-бы тот подключился через ssh к `RM-A` и сделал pull, после того, как прошёл push с `local`?

У меня прописан такой post-receive hook, но скрипт выходит с ошибкой и при ручном git pull на `RM-A` система обновляется до последней версии, хотя, если-бы скрипт прошёл удачно, то должно было выдать, что клон уже обнавлён.

```
#!/bin/bash

IP="$(ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | cut -f2 | awk '{ print $2}')"

LOG_FILE=/var/log/git.post-receive.log

export DEPLOY_APP_NAME=APP
export GIT_DIR="$(cd $(dirname $(dirname $0));pwd)"

REMOTE_USERNAME="user"
REMOTE_HOSTS="host.example.tld"

echo "$(date): ${IP} tries to change '$(hostname -f)'" >> ${LOG_FILE}

BRANCHES=()
BRANCHES+=('alpha')
BRANCHES+=('beta')
BRANCHES+=('stable')

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
        export DEPLOY_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
        export DEPLOY_OLDREV="$oldrev"
        export DEPLOY_NEWREV="$newrev"
        export DEPLOY_REFNAME="$refname"

        export DEPLOY_ROOT="/opt/${DEPLOY_APP_NAME}/${DEPLOY_BRANCH}/project/"

#       export GIT_WORK_TREE="${DEPLOY_ROOT}"

        for REMOTE_HOST in ${REMOTE_HOSTS};
        do
                if [[ " ${BRANCHES[*]} " ==  *"${DEPLOY_BRANCH}"* ]]; then
                        echo "$(date): Deploying ${DEPLOY_BRANCH} by ${IP}" >> ${LOG_FILE}

                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${REMOTE_USERNAME} ${REMOTE_HOST} 'cd ${DEPLOY_ROOT} && git branch "${DEPLOY_BRANCH}"' || echo "$(date): Custom error output"
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${REMOTE_USERNAME} ${REMOTE_HOST} 'cd ${DEPLOY_ROOT} && git checkout -f "${DEPLOY_BRANCH}"' || echo "$(date): Custom error output"
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${REMOTE_USERNAME} ${REMOTE_HOST} 'cd ${DEPLOY_ROOT} && git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/${DEPLOY_BRANCH} ${DEPLOY_BRANCH}'
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${REMOTE_USERNAME} ${REMOTE_HOST} 'cd ${DEPLOY_ROOT} && git pull'
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${REMOTE_USERNAME} ${REMOTE_HOST} 'cd ${DEPLOY_ROOT} && git reset --hard "${DEPLOY_NEWREV}"' || echo "$(date): Custom error output" && exit 1

                        echo "$(date): Deployed safely" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                fi
        done
done

exit 0
```

Если пишу в shell команду

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${REMOTE_USERNAME} ${REMOTE_HOST} 'cd ${DEPLOY_ROOT} && git reset --hard "${DEPLOY_NEWREV}"'
```

то получаю ошибку - *fatal: Could not parse object 'e88056..12d964'*,
но если пишу

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${REMOTE_USERNAME} ${REMOTE_HOST} \
  'cd ${DEPLOY_ROOT} && git pull'
```

и потом

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${REMOTE_USERNAME} ${REMOTE_HOST} \
  'cd ${DEPLOY_ROOT} && git reset --hard "${DEPLOY_NEWREV}"'
```

тогда всё работает, но не через скрипт

Пример использовал с [github thomasfr](https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9691385)

Comment: Но в целом это далеко не лучшая схема деплоя (субъективно, да). Есть ряд причин не иметь репозиторий там, где у вас хостится приложение (сайт). Достаточно копировать его туда с помощью rsync. Подробнее в [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Comment: `скрипт выходит с ошибкой` – с какой?

Comment: Nick, ошибки явной не выводит, только то, что выход non-zero, т.е. срабатывает `...  || echo "$(date): Custom error output" && exit 1` и после входа через ssh в раб. директорию, сделав pull происходит обновление, хотя должно вывести сообщение, что клон уже обновлён. 
Может быть есть другой способ делать deploy. У меня пока в голове cron для php, который будет делать git pull

Comment: Предоставленная ссылка решает вопрос, если и репозиторий и сайт находится на одном сервере, на одной машине. В моём случае 3 разных машины. Где у удалённых серверов с сайтом есть доступ к удалённому серверу с репозиторием через пуб. ключ.

Comment: там же описан способ через rsync, он как раз отлично работает с разными машинами и ssh доступом.