# Как правильно настроить git для физической копии devel хоста?

Tags: git

Имеется две площадки: product и devel. На product настроен git. Devel - полный клон product со всеми настройками, в т.ч. и git, но находящаяся на другом сервере. Вопрос: как правильно настроить git на devel, чтобы можно было мержить его с product?

Comment: Что значит "на product настроен git"? Как настроен? Что значит "правильно"? Без подробностей невозможно ответить на вопрос

Comment: Настроен, значит инициализирован и функционирует в штатном режиме.

Comment: Более конкретные вопросы:
1. Нужно ли что-то изменять в настройках git на devel (название сервера, веток и т.д.)?
2. Как подключиться к product?
3. Как обновить devel самой свежей редакцией product?

Comment: Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то вам сюда
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git

Comment: Не совсем понятен следующий момент: обязательно ли клонировать репозиторий с production на devel, если все файлы проекта уже скопированы физически с production на devel, в том числе и папка .git? Как мне в этом случае обновлять devel в случае изменения production?

Comment: Во всех источниках написано, как создавать клоны с нуля. А если продакт и девел уже есть? Как подцепить их на git и синхронизировать между собой?

Comment: Ещё раз опишу, что уже сделано:
1. Создан проект с файлами на продакт на одном сервере.
2. Файлы с продакта скопированы на девел.
3. На продакте создан git репозиторий.

Вопрос: как синхронизировать продакт и девел? Что нужно сделать на девеле? Что подразумевается под словами "клонирование" репозитория? Это копирование папки .git? Или копирование полностью проекта со всеми файлами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался, всем спасибо! 
Корректно настроил подключение к удалённому репозиторию и всё заработало.

**Update:**
Подробнее, что было сделано:

1. Удалил неправильный удалённый репозиторий (так как репозиторий git был физически скопирован с *product*, который, в свою очередь настроен на другой удалённый репозиторий) командой `git remote rm`.
2. Добавил правильный (репозиторий *product*) удалённый репозиторий командой `git remote add`.
3. В файле `~/.ssh/.config` прописал алиас для *product*, чтобы каждый раз не вводить пароль при подключении к *product*.
4. Проверил подключение при помощи команды `git remote show`.

Comment: @rjhdby какой-такой "лучший ответ", если это единственный ответ? Наличие в ответе слова "спасибо" не делает ответ автоматически "фразой "спасибо". Вот из-за низкого качества ответа (непонятно что на деле представляет собой "корректно настроил подключение", так что это вряд ли кому-то ещё когда-то поможет) его стоит удалить.

Comment: Автор, не могли бы вы подробнее рассказать, что именно и как вы настроили? Тогда ответ будет полезен будущим читателям. И получит хорошую оценку, лично я обещаю плюс. (А пока что из ответа не ясен путь решения, поэтому он фактически не ответ.)

Comment: Добавил в ответ более подробную информацию по ходу решения вопроса.

Comment: Обещанный плюс. )