# Разработка и поддержка проекта с git

Tags: git

Есть проект, который активно разрабатывается на локальном компьютере (OS Windows). После того как проект готов, необходимо его залить на рабочий Web-сервер (OS Centos). До этого я делал все это вручную - обновлял, удалял старые файлы, используя FTP-клиент. Теперь хочу поступить по умному и использовать Git. На локалке git установлен, на рабочем сервере нет.

Как можно, используя git, обновлять сайт на рабочем сервере до новой версии, которая на локалке?

P.S. видел на SO [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-git), но мне это не помогло (rsync ведь только на Linux-подобных системах).

Comment: *"rsync ведь только на Linux"* -- [не только](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html)

Comment: git это не средство для развертывания инфраструктуры. правильным вариантом будет использовать систему развертывания.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman можно по подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: посмотрите информацию об Ansible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Скачиваем и устанавливаем git для windows, например [отсюда](https://git-scm.com/download/win);
   1.1 установить настройки через powerSheell с Вашим именем и email

   $ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
   $ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
2. Устанавливаем git на [сервере](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git); 
   2.2 установить настройки через terminal с Вашим именем и email

   $ git config --global user.name "*John Doe*"
   $ git config --global user.email *johndoe@example.com*
3. Создаём аккаунт на [github](https://github.com/);
4. После - создаём репозиторий. https://github.com/new
5. Берём адрес для клонирования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Клонируем репозиторий на ПК и на сервер.

```
git clone https://github.com...project.git  /path/to/you/you_folder
```

Всё. Проект готов к работе.

Comment: `установить настройки через terminal с Вашим именем и фамилией` - имелся в виду `email`, скорее всего.

Comment: опечатался :), поправил

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick на сервер установил, все сделал. Для теста создал новый репозиторий с первым коммитом. После того, как добавил в репозиторий еще один файл, он добавился в Git, но на сервере его нет. Как так?

Comment: Надо сделать коммит и и пуш а потом пул. Как доберусь до копьютера детальнее опишу.

Comment: У Вас получилось, настроить гит?