# Как сделать игнор для git pull

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

На гите лежит папка dist, в которой лежат минифицированные css, js, которые компилируются из исходников. Допустим поменял что-то в css/js, у себя исходники перекомпилировал. Делаешь git pull - получаешь мерж конфликт на минифицированные файлы. При этом конфликта на исходники нету. Можно ли как-то настроить гит, чтобы при пуле он он:

а)игнорировал папку dist
б)перезаписывал только папку dist версией с remote

Comment: В первую очередь стоит понять зачем они в гите, если они получаются в результате компиляции?

Comment: хранить такие файлы в системе контроля версий — ошибка. если исправить её нет возможности, есть ряд [«костылей», с помощью которых можно «обхромать» эту ошибку](http://stackoverflow.com/q/773220/4827341).

Comment: @AlexeyTen Для простоты, используется cms, тем, кто её администрирует удобно писать git pull и ничего не откуда не таскать.

Comment: @Nikita а использовать Git для деплоя это тоже серьёзная ошибка.

Comment: @Nikita поддерживаю D-side: есть очень много аргументов против деплоя с помощью git. Попробуйте [деплой через`rsync`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/181472)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую к прочтению ответ D-side.

Нашёл ответ на английском SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332528/is-it-possible-to-exclude-specific-commits-when-doing-a-git-merge/3970442#3970442

Допустим Вы хотите исключить файл config.php из ветки А.

В ветке А:

1. Создайте файл .gitattributes в той же папке, что config.php, со строчкой `config.php merge=ours`. Это строчка говори гиту при мерже выбирать локальную версию файла, т.е. версию той ветки **В** которую выполняется слияние.
2. Добавьте вкомитьте и запушьте .gitattributes
3. Повторите те же действия для ветки B

Теперь выполните мерж: никаких конфликтов, все остались при своём config.php

**PS** Для моего случая достаточно было прописать только в ветке А, т.к. после мержа всё равно приходится выполнять билд папки dist. Ушёл читать про хуки, надеюсь, что при завершении пула и мержа, билд выполниться автоматически:)

Comment: Не помню откуда ссылка на английский СО, по-моему в каком-то из комментариев на русском СО взял)

Comment: это один из «костылей», про которые я упоминал в комментарии под текстом вопроса.

Answer (score 6):

Для начала замечу, что вы **держите пистолет, наведённый прямо на вашу ногу:**

- Вы держите под контролем версий файлы, которые не являются исходным кодом

  - Замусориваете историю (тратите впустую дисковое место) и усложняете обслуживание репозитория (легко получить рассинхрон между исходным кодом и результатами сборки)
- Вы используете Git для деплоя

  - Вы уверены, что у вас вся история продукта со всеми паролями когда либо в ней бывшими не торчит наружу?
    Посмотрите, не достижима ли у вас на вебсервере папка `.git`. Если достижима — объявляйте красную тревогу, оцените доступ к чему мог утечь и измените/отформатируйте/переустановите всё, что от этого зависит. В особо тяжёлых случаях лучше поставить систему заново.
- Вы используете **на сервере** `git pull`, который может создавать новые коммиты.

  - **У сервера будет собственное мнение** о том, что в репозитории. У него будет история, щедро сдобренная слияниями, о которых кроме сервера никто не знает.

Скорее всего, вам на сервере нужна совсем другая команда:

```
git fetch && git checkout refs/remotes/origin/master
```

...которая заберёт (`fetch`) новые коммиты с сервера и вытащит в рабочую область (`checkout`) состояние ветки `master` на сервере (`origin`, это имя используется для исходного репозитория по умолчанию при `git clone`).

В отличие от `git pull`, эта команда никак не смутится, увидев в репозитории переписанную историю, поскольку на локальные ветки она никак не опирается.

---

#### А по-хорошему...

Папка `dist` должна быть в файле `.gitignore` и **не существовать в репозитории**. Процесс деплоя должен состоять из сборки и загрузки результатов на сервер.

Comment: Насчёт пистолета, есть различные мнения по этому поводу, хотя я с вами согласен) Тут есть такой вопрос нужно чтобы git pull не смутился только для папки dist, но смутился для всех остальных файлов и папок.

Comment: @Nikita если у вас ещё в каждой ревизии возможны рассинхроны между исходным кодом и результатом сборки, то всё настолько плохо, что нужно срочно принимать против этого меры. Приведённая команда будет брать состояние всего репозитория, идентичное размещённому на сервере.

Comment: Чего только не бывает:) В данном случае так уже сложилось. Работают программисты различных направлений, есть скрипт deploy_content.ps1, который копирует dist в папки проекта. Поэтому редактирование стилей/скриптов заканчивается компилированием в dist, а минифицированные файлы часто дают конфликт, который не удаётся разрешить автоматически. Просто надоело для 2-х файлов писать mergetool, нашёл вот такую штуку, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332528/is-it-possible-to-exclude-specific-commits-when-doing-a-git-merge/3970442#3970442 , поставил ours

Comment: Таким образом это не для деплоя, а для разработки получилось. Спасибо за ответ, для меня он был полезен) Возможно Вы знаете, можно ли сделать так, чтобы после git pull, выполнялись ещё команды, например запуск bat файла?

Comment: @Nikita сложившееся можно и нужно менять, если оно работает криво. А касательно вашей ссылки -- можете опубликовать собственный ответ и принять его.

Comment: @Nikita какой-то из [хуков](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git) может сгодиться. `post-checkout`, например.

Comment: @Nikita поэтому я и указываю на то, что проблема глубже и решать её надо основательнее.

Comment: Да, извините, удалил тот комментарий, подумал замещение нашей версией = игнорирование, и в принципе на конкретный вопрос "Как сделать игнор для git pull" отвечает.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста добавить ссылку в свой ответ, сохранив то, что уже написано?

Comment: @Nikita ваша находка, вам за неё и репу :) Переведите ответ оттуда на русский язык, опубликуйте тут, оставив ссылку на первоисточник. Так можно.

Comment: @D-side находка-то по ссылке от Баракина. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin а, я даже внимания не обратил. Ну да ладно. Я всё равно не считаю это правильным решением и не стал бы прикладывать в свой ответ :\ Да и Александр тоже считает это костылём.

Comment: Кстати, если кто-нибудь  ручками залезет и поправит файлы на сервере, то `git checkout refs/remotes/origin/master` может блокироваться с конфликтом. Может быть, `git reset --hard HEAD; git checkout...`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin поскольку вышеприведённый совет приведёт к тому, что рабочее дерево будет постоянно в состоянии detached HEAD, я что-то не очень представляю, как могут возникнуть конфликты. Чекаут вытягивает версию из коммита "как есть", разве нет?