# Как исключить файл из слияния веток в git?

Tags: git

У меня есть три ветки  в репозитории.

```
master
slave 1
slave 2
```

есть один файл package.json

Он должен отличаться в каждой из веток.

Но если я выполняю комманду  `git merge master`

У меня сливаются эти две ветки.

Как исключить package.json из слияния веток что бы на каждой ветке оставалась своя версия ?

Comment: прозреваю [дубликат по смыслу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416219/178576) и [дубликат по форме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662675/178576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В корне репозитория в требуемой ветке (например, `slave 1`) необходимо создать файл `.gitattributes`.

В файл добавить строчку `package.json merge=ours`.

Добавить файл `.gitattributes` в фиксацию.

Указать стратегию слияния `git config merge.ours.driver true` (вроде она по умолчанию `true`, также можно через `--global`)

Произвести `git merge master`