# Удобный способ переноса проекта на сервер

Tags: node.js, сервер, развертывание, обновление

Имеется проект (node.js - хотя это не важно), который разрабатывается на локальной машине и периодически переносится на сервер.
В принципе, можно было бы каждый раз просто стирать папку проекта на сервере и заменять ее новой - заново залитой с локальной машины. Но дело в том, что некоторые папки и проекта, при чем очень большие (конкретно: node_modules), перезаписывать не нужно. Приходится вручную создавать архив, исключая из него ненужные папки. А на сервере тоже предварительно стирать все кроме некоторых папок и только потом заменять.
Как можно автоматизировать данную процедуру?
(На локальной машине - windows, на сервере - Linux)

Comment: Для начала, попробуйте использовать git

Comment: @Alexander А что именно Вы имеете в виду? Использовать GitHub (я не всегда хочу делать проект общедоступным) или заливать файл .git на сервер?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/183314

Comment: git push - с локального компа, git pull - на сервере. Серверо-зависимый код (вроде данных подключения к БД) - выносится в .gitignore, или же можно его оставить - но на разных серверах делать симлинки на разные конфиг-файлы.