# Путь к папке проекта под git

Tags: git

Есть домен domain.ru на вебсервере, в нём папка web - в неё смотрит сервер, т.е. это www.

В папке `domain.ru` делаю `git init` добавляю удалённый репозиторий, тяну проект в папку web сразу. Готово. Захожу, смотрю и вижу что в папке `web` тоже создалась папка `.git` а я хотел этого избежать, что бы она осталась выше `www`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Директория `.git` — это, собственно, репозиторий git. Она появляется там, где вы делаете `git init`.

Git работает с файлами в так называемой рабочей директории (worktree). По умолчанию это та же директория, в которой лежит `.git`. Но с помощью параметра `--work-tree` можно работать с другой рабочей директорией:

```
git --work-tree=/srv/www/domain.ru pull
```

Но хранить `.git` на сервере всё равно рискованно. Если можете, организуйте деплой через rsync:

```
# с другой машины, из репозитория с файлами
rsync --delete -acvz /site user@server:/srv/www/domain.ru

# опции rsync:
# --delete extraneous files from dest dir
# -a archive mode; same as -rlptgoD
# -c skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size.
# -v increase verbosity
# -z compress file data during the transfer
```

Comment: Стало лучше но с pull что-то не сложилось
`$ git --work-tree=web pull

Password for '...@bitbucket.org':
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (15/15), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/...
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: @fosh4455 вы должны эту команду запускать из директории где лежит `.git`, а значение параметра — путь от этой директории до `web`. Всё так?

Comment: да, всё именно так и делал

Comment: @fosh4455 то есть у вас в `domain.ru/` лежат `.git/` и `web`, так?

Comment: @fosh4455 вообще вот есть большой ответ про деплой через git: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/181472

Comment: там чё-т как-то непрофессионально )) Ладно пойду на западный стак схожу спрошу...

Comment: @fosh4455 непрофессионально? Хм, расскажите подробнее, чего не хватает.

Comment: развёртывание без репозитория не вариант из-за удаления файлов вручную, а дальше версия с сервером сразу идёт, обычно делают архитектуру типа локальный репо -> github/bitbucket -> сервер с проектом (но без git-сервера на нём). Я начинаю догадываться что в моём случае bare-репозиторий подошёл бы, но надо ещё почитать

Comment: `из-за удаления файлов вручную` – можно поподробнее в этом месте? Вам нужно что-то удалять вручную или вы думаете что при таком способе вам придется удалять вручную? Если второй вариант — то не придётся, за вас это сделает `rsync --delete`.

Comment: *--delete-after* бывает полезно

Comment: @0andriy кстати да, выглядит разумно.