# скачивание только части git папки

Tags: git, github

Не знаю даже как это назвать. Использую github больше не из надобности, а чтобы просто быть в курсе чего и как. Прочитал множество статей и понял, что многие работают через различные препроцессоры, то есть имеют папки для билда и исходники. В моем случае это папка src с исходниками, и папка dist с уже рабочими файлами. Вопрос в том, как через гит залить на сервер только содержимое папки dist, при этом, чтобы на сервере она появлялась уже в нужной папке. То есть к примеру у меня есть папка project1, и при клонировании части репозитория у меня все файлы сразу падали в project1, а не в project1/dist.

Что за команды мне нужно использовать, возможно ли это сделать, и что больше меня интересует, нормальная ли это практика? как люди в основном поступают?

Буду очень благодарен, хочется делать все по уму, а не сикось накось

Comment: Рабочие (скомпилированные) файлы вообще обычно не надо версионировать. Их же всегда можно восстановить из кода.

Comment: Если вы хотите развертывание (деплой) организовать, то вариант через гит — не единственный и точно не лучший. Можно, например, через rsync деплоить, если на сервере линукс. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704730/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin, `rsync` есть и нативно собранный даже под Windows.