# auto Update web site from bitbucket

Tags: php, сервер, bitbucket

мы хотим обновлять сайт через битбакет.

когда добавляем и merge делаем на битбакет хотим чтобы этот код автоматически добавлялся на сервере.

Comment: А теперь тоже самое, но  только по русски... Так как это сайт русскоязычный...   And now the same thing, but only in Russian ... Since this is a Russian-language site ...

Comment: мы хотим обновлять сайт через битбакете. когда добавляем и мерге делаем на битбоккет хотим што этат кок автоматически добавлялся на сервере .

Comment: В место комментария, это надо оформить в вопросе.. нажми править вопрос и опиши вопрос по русский

Comment: Вероятный дубликат вопроса [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472)