# Git + автоматизировать публикацию приложения в IIS?

Tags: .net, git, непрерывная-интеграция

Допустим мы разрабатываем серверное приложение и у нас есть сервер git, и допустим несколько программистов делают коммиты в этот репозиторий.

У меня вопрос, кто и как потом публикует скомпилированную сборку на сервер IIS? Это должен делать какой-то один специально обученный человек, который будет скачивать себе локально последнюю версию, компилировать ее и отправлять на сервер IIS или этот процесс можно как то автоматизировать.

Слышал что есть системы непрерывной интеграции но в случае если у нас IIS то мы можем их использовать?

Comment: Да, решается связкой любого билд сервера (Teamcity?) + любой системы деплоя (например, Octopus, или просто копированием файлов в папку IIS, как последнего шага билда)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо тоже полезная ссылка, но там увы случай для сервера на linux, в моем случае интересует Windows Server

Comment: перечитал ответ к указанному вопросу. не встретил абсолютно ничего операционно-системно-специфичного.