# Git + локальная разработка + боевой сервер

Tags: git, rsync

Локальная разработка ведется с использованием git и OpenServer. Какой оптимальный способ настройки синхронизации локальной копии и удаленной копии на боевом сервере?

Первый вариант. Для редакторов есть ftp-модули. Сохранил файл локально -> он же отправился на сервер по ftp. Неплохо, но не совсем надежно. Редко, но бывает, что файл не уходит на сервер, приходится его сохранять повторно.

Второй вариант, это установить git на боевой сервер и с него пулить проект.

Третий вариант, это использовать rsync.

Пробовал только первый вариант. Подскажите в двух словах как это лучше организовать или хотя бы в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Continuous integration. Например, [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)