# Установка Git на сервер

Tags: git, github

Всем привет.

Ищу по интернету, не могу найти подробный пошаговый гайд, как установить гит на удаленный сервер. То, что нахожу, там пишут про то, что это нарушает безопасность и может быть утечка информации. Поэтому, если кто знает, где почитать/посмотреть или сам написать, пожалуйста, поделитесь инфой.

Задача тривиальная. Есть локальный сервер. Есть Гитхаб. И есть хостинг с сайтом. Не знаю точно, как всё должно быть устроенно, но цель такая. Я вношу правки на локальном сервере, потом пишу команды гита коммит, пуш, это уходит я так понимаю На гитхаб. И вот тут проблема. Как с гитхаба теперь данные отправить на удаленный сервер с сайтом? Я думал так, что нужно установить туда гит и всё такое, но в интернете пишут, что типа это не безопасно. Так как же всё-таки реализовать эту задачу?

Везде советуют эту ссылку:
[Вот этот пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-git)

Но этот ответ мне мало что даёт, как раз метод развертки, который описан снизу и считается небезопасным. Так что же делать? Лучше было бы какой-нибудь тутор на эту тему, чтобы лучше понять, как всё устроенно.

Comment: На сервере ставить git не нужно, нужно налаживать нормальный процесс развёртывания (с Ansible, Docker и т.п.)

Comment: По ссылке в первом ответе предлагается rsync, он вполне безопасен без каких-либо утечек

Comment: Так как грамотнее сделать, с помощью Ansible или с rsync? Спасибо за ответ!!!

Comment: На один сайт `rsync` подойдёт, а вот когда их уже становится два или ещё больше, то головная боль будет только без `ansible`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Настраивайте CI/CD на автоматический деплой после каждого коммита.

[Пример простого конфига для github actions](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/master/ci/blank.yml), [пример конфига для деплоя gitlab](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1964087)

Comment: Спасибо, еще бы инфы побольше))) А так благодарочка)