# Как правильно деплоить Git проект на продакшн сервер

Tags: linux, git, хостинг, развертывание

Только сегодня понял, как сильно ошибался при работе с Git, и до сих пор не понимаю как делать правильно.

---

Что имеется:

- Проект (В приоритете PHP, но естественно присутствует JS(исходники и запутанные через обфускатор),CSS и прочее).
- Локальная рабочая машина на котором и пишется код.
- Git репозиторий.
- Виртуальный хостинг.

---

Ранее делал все так:
На локальной машине писал весь проект - пушил в GitHub - и уже с GitHub, методом **git pull**, добавлял изменения на виртуальный хостинг.

Но появилась потребность **не загружать исходники** JS на хостинг и оставить только те, которые были пройдены через обфускатор.

И узнал, что с распростертыми руками **отдавал свои конфиги** и прочее через папку .git на хостинге, которые были доступны по **https://test.example/.git/config.**

---

Как мне поступать? Можете ли обьяснить **как правильно деплоить проект в продакшн**, **без исходников** JS и папок, по типу **.git**?

Comment: то, что в заголовке — [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576). два других вопроса (про обфускацию и каталог .git) — не имеют отношения ни к остальной части вопроса, ни друг к другу. в общем, три вопроса в одном. в таком виде надо закрывать.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin
Большое спасибо за помощь. 
Прям очень помогли, лучший ответ который мог получить на всем сайте.

Comment: @IvanGa весьма странно приходить в сообщество и диктовать условия как тебе удобно здесь быть. Здесь помогают ТЕБЕ. Добровольно! Бескорысно! И в том случае, если ты следуешь правилам ресурса. И вполне резонно Александр попросил тебя следовать правилам. Только ссылку в руки не дал. Я это сделаю за него: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Любой вопрос можно разложить на подвопросы. У человека была одна проблема, он про нее и спросил максимально подробно, объяснив со всем подробностями (из которых вы и выдавили другие, якобы, вопросы)

Comment: @Andrew, а что в заданном мной вопросе не так, можете конкретно указать на ошибку?
В вопросе существует один единственный вопрос: "Можете ли обьяснить как правильно деплоить проект в продакшн?". Вам не понравилось что все было описано в подробностях? Окей, оставил бы только вопрос - большинство бы дало ненужные советы, которые не относятся к сути моей проблемы. Или вам не понравилось что слишком много букв? Давайте я разобью данный вопрос на этой странице на несколько разных. Так вы мне предлагаете? Первый раз вижу таких людей на сайте, которым просто не лень зайти указать, чем просто помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно настройками веб-сервера запретить доступ к директории `.git`.

А вообще, хорошая практика, когда `DOCUMENT_ROOT` не в корне проекта, а в поддиректории.

```
.git/
js-sources/
public/ <- Вот это докрут вебсервера
other_dirs/
```

Тогда из веба будут недоступны ни .git, ни js-sources.