# Перенести репозиторий с хостинга на локальный компьютер

Tags: git, битрикс

Есть хостинг с сайтом на битриксе, к которому подключаюсь по SSH, в котором инициализирован репозиторий. Как перенести его на локальный компьютер, чтобы просто пушить изменения в нужную ветку? Гугл не смог помочь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

1) Свяжите репозиторий на хостинге с github и запуште проект:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<your-github-username>/<your-project-name>.git
git push -u origin master
```

2) Затем на своей локальной машине клонируйте репозиторий

```
git clone https://github.com/<your-github-username>/<your-project-name>.git
```

Думаю про `git push` на локальной машине и `git pull` на хостинге после изменений проекта объяснять нет необходимости.