# Как работает git удаленный репозиторий

Tags: git, git-remote

При пуше с локалки на удаленный origin/master все пушится норм. Захожу на удаленный сервер проверяю, коммит есть.
По факту файлы на удаленном сервере, которые затронул пуш, не изменены, а git status на удаленном сервере показывает эти файлы в статусе modified.
Я что-то не понимаю? почему файлы не изменены? и как появляется modified?

Comment: А в рабочей копии на удаленом сервере pull делался?

Comment: Если вы хотите чтобы на удалённом сервере файлы тоже обновлялись, то вам [нужно сделать ещё несколько шагов](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2011/git-deploy-made-simple/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

хранилище («репозиторий») git — это то, что вы можете видеть в каталоге `.git`. вот содержимое этого каталога у вновь созданного хранилища:

```
$ tree .git
.git
├── branches
├── config
├── description
├── HEAD
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── pre-receive.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── objects
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
└── refs
    ├── heads
    └── tags
```

в каталоге `.git/objects` хранятся объекты (типов commit, tree, blob), из которых можно извлечь содержимое тех файлов, которые и составляют ваш проект. файлы эти для хранилища — вещь сугубо опциональная. без них хранилище отлично функционирует (яркий пример вы можете наблюдать на сервере github.com). а вот вам для **работы** нужны именно эти файлы. они и называются потому «**рабочей** копией/деревом/каталогом« («working copy/tree/directory»).

когда вы «пушите» в удалённое хранилище, программа git передаёт **объекты**.

если из объектов хранилища, в которое вы передали новую порцию объектов, когда-то было развёрнута «рабочая копия», то, естественно, никакого обновления файлов в этой копии не произойдёт. файлы, составляющие «рабочую копию», будут рассинхронизованы с состоянием самого хранилища.

чтобы избежать такой рассинхронизации, программа git по умолчанию отказывается «пушить» в хранилище, из которого развёрнута «рабочая копия» (для обхода этого ограничения требуется внести изменение в конфигурацию такого хранилища).

нормальной практикой является передача объектов в хранилище **без** «рабочей копии» (т.н. bare-хранилище), из которого впоследствии объекты (командой *pull*) забираются в хранилище **с** «рабочей копией». где из объектов уже и извлекается новое содержимое для файлов «рабочей копии».

судя по изложенному в вопросе, у вас нарушается эта нормальная практика. лучше так, конечно, не делать, но если от вас тут ничего не зависит, то привести содержимое файлов «рабочей копии» к тому состоянию, что содержится в объектах хранилища, можно, например, командой:

```
 $ git reset --hard
```

будьте внимательны и осмотрительны: эта команда затрёт все локальные изменения в файлах «рабочей копии».

Comment: Если идти по методу --bare , не совсем понятно как в рабочую директорию сделать pull, если рабочая директория и bare репозиторий на одном сервере, в разных папках. Как настроить bare репозиторий для рабочей папки в качестве remote. Проще говоря как настроить remote из другой папки на том же сервере

Comment: попробую угадать, что же вас интересует на самом деле: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576 . но если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос