# Использование репозитория как директорию проекта на "боевом" сервере

Tags: git

Имеем такую ситуацию: веб проект в гит репозиторий. Добавление новых фишек происходит в ветке dev. Текущий рабочий релиз находится в ветке main.

Хочется реализовать следующую идею. Подскажите, насколько она хороша и стоит ли воспользоваться ею. Возможно существует вариант лучше этого?

Текущее состояния репозитория в ветке dev находится на поддомене dev.domain.com. При совместной работе постоянно делаем туда комиты, что-то правим, откатываем, изменяем и т.д. Когда хотим показать клиенту результат работы, делаем git pull внутри нашего поддомена на dev.domain.com, и показываем ему результат. Если все ОК, то мержим эту ветку в main, после чего пулим ее с domain.com, тем самым выпустив релизную версию продукта.

Comment: Проходили не раз. Не только Вам пришла в голову такая гениальная идея. Даже Яндексу приходила. Но у нее есть один изъян. большущий такой. Если где то что то пойдет не так (а оно обязательно пойдет), то все Ваши сорцы утекут.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576

Comment: @KoVadim, часто проблема не столько в исходниках (если нагло не воровалась чужая IP), сколько в истории... Там внутрикорпоротивного гуано может хватить на затопление конторы в два счёта.

Comment: @0andriy конечно. Имея на руках история разработки можно много чего узнать.  Файлы с паролями часто бывают (которые случайно добавили, а потом удалили и думаю, что все ок)