# Добавить папку .git к существующему сайту

Tags: git, gitlab

Я веду разработку проекта в phpStorm, создал папку .git через git init. Сделал какие-то коммиты и сделал пуш в гитлаб.

Застрял на моменте переноса папки .git на сервер с сайтом. Достаточно ли просто скопировать папку .git с домашнего ПК на сервер и сделать git pull ?

Меня не интересует вопрос автодеплоя сейчас. Хотелось бы хотя бы наладить работу через гитлаб и гит пул. Но по-моему просто скопировать папку недостаточно?

Comment: Что-то вы всё напутали. Если вы копируете папку .git, то делать git pull нет никакого смысла, ведь всё актуальное содержимое в ней уже есть. А вот если вы не копируете папку .git, то как раз нужно делать git clone и git pull чтобы папка появилась

Comment: но лучше потратить буквально пару минут и написать простой скрипт, который будет выкладывать Ваш код (деплоить). Это даже быстрее, чем задавать тут вопрос.

Comment: @andreymal, я так понял просто скопировать папку недостаточно. может вы знаете, что после копирования нужно еще делать, чтобы синхронизация с гитлаб заработала? я ведь обновляю сначала гитлаб, а потом забираю изменения через git pull

Comment: @KoVadim, вы правы, но я даже в такой простой ситуации пока не понимаю, что делать. Хотелось бы понять, как подцепить гитлаб к существующему сайту(

Comment: scp с скриптом и готово. и дальше деплой - это просто запуск скрипта. В будущем его можно подцепить на хук коммита/пуша и все будет супер

Comment: [вообще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576), а в частности, безотносительно куда скопировали каталог `.git`, чтобы развернуть рабочую копию файлов (в каталоге, содержащем `.git` как подкаталог), надо выполнить команду `checkout`.