# Help! Git pull в Linux меняет владельца на новые файлы

Tags: linux, git, chown

Выполняю

```
git pull
```

команду на сервере, владелец файлов изменяется и приходится вручную выставлять

```
chown www:www test.php
```

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы, когда я выполняю `git pull`,
владельцем файлов автоматически становился `www:www` ?

Comment: Запускать git под пользователем www

Comment: Ну или делать `chown` после pull-а (если получится)

Comment: На самом деле вышеприведенные советы хороши, но архаичны (@andreymal, JFYI). Нет, вам не надо делать ни то, ни другое при правильно настроенном SELinux, пусть система сама этим занимается.

Comment: Не оно? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016782/5430535

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git