# gitlab-runner: как запустить от имени root?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-runner

Я не разбираюсь в CI/CD, начал изучать только. Сделал простую настройку. При запуске получаю ошибку

```
cd /var/www/public_html && git pull origin dev
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

Как я понял, процесс запущен от пользователя, в которого нету прав на эти файлы (владелец - root).

Вопрос: могу ли я запустить gitlab-runner от root пользователя?

Comment: В принципе можете, однако вместо этого следует переделать тесты так, чтобы они никогда не требовали привилегий суперпользователя.

Comment: я просто не знаю, как правильно сделать пул

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576