# Как создать git репозиторий на рабочем компьюетере и сервере , без посредников типа (github, bitbacked)?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Для мелких проектов хочется иметь возможность синхронизации через репозиторий со своим сервером (CENTos7). Как это можно сделать что бы не использовать сервисы посредники. Спасибо.

Интересуют все шаги.

- Создание репозитория если это отличается от создания репозитория по-умолчанию.
- пуш и пулл (со своего сервера на рабочую машину)
- и тд

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Answer (score 2):

Данному вопросу посвящена целая глава официального учебника по git:

https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2 глава 4 Git на сервере.

Если кратко:

Создаёте на сервере пользователя git. Можно выбрать любой логин, но так делают чаще.

Можно очень сильно ограничить его в правах за пределами папки где будут репозитории.

Даёте ему доступ по ssh.

Создаёте на сервере bare-репозиторий.

На локальной машине или клонируете этот репозиторий или подключаете как remote к существующему. URL будет иметь вид `ssh://[user@]server/path/to/repo.git`, или `[user@]server:/path/to/repo.git`, для git они равнозначны